# VBA Conditional Find and Replace MS Word

Tags: replace, ms-word

I have a spec document in which I've written a VBA macro for which "toggles" between two views of itself.  There are logic statements written out like:

If Q.1 = 2, then skip to Q.3

The client reviews the logic with question numbers and the programmers read through the logic with variable names.

If intro1 = 2, then skip to home1

I created two arrays that correspond to one another to perform a Find a Replace so one can switch back and forth between displaying Question Numbers and Variables.

Of course a comprehensive solution is never easy.  With this of course, if there are any instructions in the document that I would want to be "exempt" from being found and replaced.

So now I am thinking that I need to instead of doing a Find and Replace All, I need to do the "Find Next" and evaluate what is found and based on the font or font size to determine if it should be replaced.  Is there an object in VBA that is returned that can be accessed when you perform a "Find" that I can check the properties of?  Basically I was to be able to discriminate between font size to determine if it should be replaced or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this. As far as the code is concerned, if you set a range to ActiveDocument.Range, then use the .Find object of that range, Word should successively return Range objects that "cover" the found text. Depending on how much control you have over the document content, one way that you can easily mark texts to be found is to create a Character style and apply it to all those texts. Then you can do something like this:

```
Sub multipleFIndsUsingAStyle()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
With rng.Find
  .Text = ""
  ' Create a style called findStyle and
  ' apply it to the texts you want to find
  .Style = "findStyle"
  .Forward = True
  .Execute
  While .Found
    Debug.Print rng.Start, rng.End
    .Execute
  Wend
End With
Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

There are a couple of completely different approaches you could use. One would be to insert the two alternate texts using fields, along the following lines (there are several ways to do this):

Use VBA to create Document Variables called q1, v1, q2, v2 etc., with the values Q.1, intro1, Q.3, home1, etc. Like this

With ActiveDocument.Variables
 .Item("q1").Value = "Q.1"
 .Item("v1").Value = "intro1"
 .Item("q2").Value = "Q.3"
 .Item("v2").Value = "home1"
' We'll use this one to toggle the names
 .Item("qv").Value = "q"
End With

For each number/variable, insert a nested field like this

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "{ DOCVARIABLE qv }{ SEQ q }" }
```

(*All* the {} need to be the special field brace characters that you can insert in Windows Word using ctrl-F9).

Then use

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("qv").Value = "q" 
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```

to display the numbers and

```
ActiveDocument.Variables("qv").Value = "v" 
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```

to display the names. In this case, the users would be able to see the field codes, which you may not want.